# What happens when I draw cards if I've built the Library and the Observatory?

Tags: citadels

In Citadels it's possible to build both the Library and Observatory:

**Library**

> If you choose to draw cards when you take an action, you keep both of the cards you have drawn.

**Observatory**

> If you choose to draw cards when you take an action, you draw three cards, keep one of your choice, and put the other two on the bottom of the deck.

What happens when I draw district cards when I have both districts in my city?  Do I draw three cards and keep all of them, or do I draw three cards and keep two of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Q: What if a player has both Library
> and Observatory in his city? How do
> their effects combine?
>
> A: If this
> player draws cards, he draws three and
> keeps two.

[(Source)](http://www.faidutti.com/index.php?Module=mesjeux&id=328&fichier=105)

That's straight from the horse's mouth, so to speak.

Comment: This answer is unsatisfying, and feels like bad game design decisions. Because this is precisely what the rules are for the observatory, which means the library provides no additional value.

Answer (score 6):

I'm inclined to say you should try and meet as much of the criteria as possible.  That said, you would:

1. Draw three cards
2. Keep both (both meaning `two`) of the cards
3. Put the remaining cards (one) on the bottom of the deck.

Comment: This answer is unsatisfying, and feels like bad game design decisions. Because this is precisely what the rules are for the observatory, which means the library provides no additional value.